# Lacking await operators?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin

Error comes up for the method requiring await operators but where do I put them and what is an await operator and async and Task? :)

```
 public async void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {

        _currentLocation = location;
        if (_currentLocation == null)
        {
            _locationText.Text = "Unable to determine your location. Try again in a short while.";
        }
        else
        {
            _locationText.Text =  string.Format("{0:f6},{1:f6}", _currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);
            as

        }
    }
```

I want specific help in the example above :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19985988/2850543 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to and when use \`async\` and \`await\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-to-and-when-use-async-and-await)

Comment: To address your edit of "I want specific help in the example above": If you read the docs on async, await, and Task, you will understand how to fix your problem. You won't get far if you don't understand your tools.

Comment: @TingAli: You'll find that `async` adoption works best if you approach it the opposite way. That is, first make your "leaves" call async APIs and `await` them, then make the containing methods `async` and `await` them, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove asycn keyword from method's signature !

```
public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
```